# How to do substring a word in excel and add one letter and convert into upper case

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on excel sheet where I am trying to use this function (find or extract or left or right ) to get the particular value and add _ at the end of word

For example

> dlxlep1

I want it in capital letter

> DLXLE_1

Similarly

> hubudp1

I want it as

> HUBUD_1

I am trying using find function but it was not working as expected

Here is the one I tried

```
=left(A1,5)
```

Comment: Please post your efforts. Is the string always a series of letters followed by a single number?

Comment: Please don't give negative

Comment: Yes it will be like this 

dlxlep1
dlxlep2
ukathp1
czjazp1
hubudp1

Comment: Is it always 6 letters?

Comment: no it will vary

Comment: I given the values some time 6 or 7 or 8 like need to remove the letter p in that and add _1 in the end

Comment: I'll try again. Is the string always a series of letters followed by a single number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)) &"_" &  RIGHT(A1,1)
```

[image]

This assumes a **single decimal digit** at the end of the string.

**EDIT#1:**

To clip off the **last character** before the decimal digit, use:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)) &"_" &  RIGHT(A1,1)
```

Comment: Need to remove p

Comment: for example 
dlxlep1

Dlxle_1

Comment: I need to remove the character p in the end before the number

Comment: @Mahadevan  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

use `UPPER()` to covert the string to upper case. If the last character is always a single digit parse out the left side with `LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` using LEN (length) to determine the length less one. Add the underscore character `&"_"&` followed by the rightmost character `RIGHT(A1,1)`. Together it should look like `=UPPER(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&"_"&RIGHT(A1,1)`
Edit: if the "p" is always before the number then it should be left -2 
 `=UPPER(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&"_"&RIGHT(A1,1)`  or even `=UPPER(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,1,"_"))`

Answer (score 0):

## REPLACE feat. SEARCHREV

### In VBE

`SEARCHREV` is a user-defined function (UDF), which will do the same as `SEARCH` (case-insensitive i.e. `AA=Aa=aa`), except from the end of a string.

Copy the code to a standard module (in VBE go to `Insert>>Module`).

```vb
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Returns the position of the last occurence of
'             a case-INsensitive string within a string. Read only. Long.
' Inputs:
'   UseString       Required. String expression being searched.
'   SearchString    Required. String expression being searched for.
'   RightPosition   Optional. Numeric expression that sets the starting position
'                   for each search. If omitted, –1 is used i.e. the search
'                   begins at the last character position.
'                   If start contains Null, an error occurs.
'*******************************************************************************
Function SEARCHREV(UseString As String, SearchString As String, _
    Optional RightPosition As Long = -1) As Long
  Application.Volatile
  SearchREV = InStrRev(UseString, SearchString, RightPosition, vbTextCompare)
End Function
'*******************************************************************************
```

### In Excel

Your question can be reformulated like this:

**Replace the last occurrence of the letter P with an underscore (_)
and apply capital (uppercase) letters to a string.**

The position of the last occurrence of the letter **P** is easily found with the `SEARCHREV` function: `=SEARCHREV(A1,"P")`. This result is exactly what the `REPLACE` function needs as its second parameter: `=REPLACE(A1,SEARCHREV(A1,"P"),1,"_")`. Now we apply the uppercase: `=UPPER(REPLACE(A1,SEARCHREV(A1,"P"),1,"_"))`. When **P** is not found, `SEARCHREV` will return 0, which will cause `REPLACE` to produce an error. Therefore we have to handle it in an `IF` statement before we run the rest `=IF(SEARCHREV(A1,"P")=0;"";...`

If the data starts in `A1`, paste the following formula in `B1`.

```
=IF(SEARCHREV(A1,"P")=0,"",UPPER(REPLACE(A1,SEARCHREV(A1,"P"),1,"_")))
```

[image]